# Setting up a PHP 5.2 server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, drupal

I am not sure if this is the proper place for this, so I apologize if I should ask it elsewhere.

I am attempting to setup an old Drupal 5 site just for the purpose of being able to view it short term. To do this I need to install PHP 5.2 on the web server (Ubuntu 10.04). Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? I can't find a simple way to install old versions of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a problem, as you probably know PHP-5.2 is been dead for some time now, so you can't just `apt-get install php`. The best way to go is to compile it yourself.

You can grab a copy from the [github PHP repository](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/php-5.2.17), and the follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.2.17/INSTALL) (under ubuntu you'll need first to install the meta package *build-essential* to get all the tools needed to compile it).

Be aware that you should not run php5.2 in production by now!

PS: You'll probably have a better answer if you try superuser or serverfault.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am about to try your suggestion. I realize that it isn't ideal for me to use PHP 5.2, but I only need the site temporally so it isn't really worthwhile updating everything.